# Should I store BLOB length in my MySQL/MariaDB table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, blob

I'm looking at storing BLOBs in my MariaDB and streaming them out to web-based clients when necessary.

I'd prefer to let the client know the length of the response in the headers, which means I need the file-length before I've read the whole thing from the database. I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Store the length of the blob in the database in a separate column
2. `SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(blob_field), blob_field FROM table WHERE id=?`

I'm wondering about that `SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(blob_field)` in there. The database *must* know the blob length already, but it the engine actually smart enough to understand that `OCTET_LENGTH(blob_field)` can be immediately known? Or will the engine read the whole BLOB field and actually count the bytes each time I execute the `SELECT` (ignoring caching, of course)?

Comment: I strongly suspect based on [the code](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/1c587481966abc7a9ad5309d0a91ca920f7a5657/sql/item_func.cc#L3076) that the blob is retrieved and passed in full to the `OCTET_LENGTH` function. It won't byte by byte count, the number is there, but there isn't the logic to lazy load the contents if the function needs it. I'd suggest a generated column of the length.

Answer (score 0):

Internally BLOBS (and other non fixed length types) are always stored with length, so length functions will access the length information (without it, it would be even impossible to step over them byte by byte without knowing the end).

Since the length of a BLOB is also transferred in client/server protocol, you can retrieve the field information to get the correct length of the blob (see max length of --column-info output)

```
$ mysql test --column-type-info
MySQL [test]> create table t1 (id int, a blob);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.060 sec)

MySQL [test]> insert into t1 values (1, x'0003040003');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.021 sec)

MySQL [test]> select a from t1 where id=1;
Field   1:  `a`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   `test`
Table:      `t1`
Org_table:  `t1`
Type:       BLOB
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     65535
Max_length: 5
Decimals:   0
Flags:      BLOB BINARY
```

Comment: Also if the BLOB weren't stored with its length, there'd be no reason to have `TINYBLOB`, `MEDIUMBLOB`, or `LONGBLOB`. The different types of BLOB encode their length in one byte, two bytes, three bytes, or four bytes.

Comment: @Bill: Depends on the storage engine

Comment: I think unless a specific storage engine is mentioned, it's safe to assume InnoDB, since it has been the default storage engine for MySQL for years.

Comment: InnoDB has 8 bytes for length, but only last 4 bytes are used, regardless of the blob type.

Comment: I see. That's interesting, I did not know that.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I asked whether or not `LENGTH()` or `OCTET_LENGTH()` was smart enough to *use* this information, not about whether or not the information was *there*. It's obviously *present*, but is it used in those particular cases? I could imagine that the implementation of `LENGTH()` for example doesn't have access to that field-level information as it's executing.

Comment: You asked if there is an overhead to retrieve the length via length/octet_length: I answered with a clear no. For all non fixed length types, the length is always stored and retrieved. And retrieving length via these function is overhead, since the length will be also sent 1) in metadata 2) in raw data (and in this case length encoded) of the client server protocol.

Answer (score 0):

`LENGTH(col)` gives the octet length.

If these blobs are 'large', consider having them as files on your server, and use other mechanisms for letting them fetch them, such as HTML's `<img ...>`.

I assume you are familiar with what it will take to escape the strings as they are being sent?

I think HTTP has a mechanism for requesting part of a file, given a byte offset and length.  (I had to use it for video downloading 15 years ago, but I don't remember the details.)  MySQL could provide the URL and length, then the client does the rest of the work without any further work by MySQL.

Keep in mind that, although there is a 4GB limit on `LONGBLOB`, there are other things (buffers, etc) that make it awkward to work with anything bigger than 16MB.

Comment: I prefer the database for a variety of reasons, primarily because in this clustered environment, there is no "*the* disk". HTTP Range requests are great, but not a consideration, here. BLOB fields should be able to be streamed rather than fitting into that 16MiB packet size. I'm looking at the Java APIs to make sure I'm telegraphing my intent to stream as best as I can. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm currently using `ResultSet.getBinaryStream()` but it looks like `ResultSet.getBlob().getBinaryStream()` may be better? I'd prefer the former as it's more compact, but I'll see what happens with a 32MiB file either way.

Comment: Looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/760850/276232) has some good information. I think I'll stick with `getBinaryStream`.

Comment: It seems this may not actually be possible without outrageous `max_packet_size` values. I'm trying to upload a test file > 16MiB and I can't see to get Connector/J and MariaDB to take it no matter how I use the API: streams, blobs, etc. I always run into either `max_packet_size` exceeded or `max_long_data_size` (which is deprecated and replaced by `max_packet_size`).